# Using libgit2 to git pull merge commit (cpp)

Tags: c++, merge, push, pull, libgit2

I m trying to use libgit2 to made a pull/merge/push from and to a remote repository.

Unfortunatly look like i use it wrong.

So basically i do a pull, then try to merge it with merge_head_from_fetchhead

When i look at the result, the merge commit have two commit parent which are the same, and file from remote are missing.

Code is located here : [Code on Gist : NotesModel.cpp line 85](https://gist.github.com/khertan/cd7ea4a28e80190c9632#file-notesmodel-cpp-L85)
The method trying to do the Pull Merge Push is void NotesModel::pullMergePush() 
Yeah i know, that s original :)

Thx a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're never calling `git_merge` to do the merge.  You're setting up a `merge_head`, which is what describes the changes you want to merge, then immediately freeing it.

You need to pass the `merge_head` to `git_merge`.